# Examples of natural proofs by induction exercises which needs 3 or more base cases?

Tags: induction, big-list

I am teaching proof by induction next week, so I am looking for new some good examples.
I'd like some natural (so not just some linear recursion depending on three previous terms) problems where three or more base cases are needed.

The mathematical objects should be easy (so no graph theory).

**My go-to example is the following:** Prove that for every $n \geq 6$, one can find a subdivision of a square into $n$ smaller squares.
The base cases are for $n=6,7,8$, and the induction proof boils down to that if $n$ is possible, then $n+3$ is possible (by subdividing a square in the subdivision into 4 smaller squares).

Comment: How about something like iterating the map that sums the cubes of the digits?    [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2802364/properties-of-the-recurrent-sum-of-cubes-of-the-digits-of-integers).  The logic is:  show that any sufficiently large number becomes smaller under this map, so you only need to consider what happens with finitely many cases.

Comment: @lulu That's a different flavor of proof, where you reduce it to a finite computation. What would the induction hypothesis be in this proof, for example?

Comment: Proof by induction:  the claim is true for $n≤2916$ (by direct check), so now let $N>2916$ be the least counterexample.  Since $F(N)<N$, where $F$ denotes one iteration of the map, the claim must be true for $F(N)$, but then it must be true for $N$ as well.

Comment: Should say:  I didn't mean $2916$ to be optimal there...$2916=F(9999)$ so that's the greatest value $F(N)$ can have for any $4$ digit number.  Seemed like a natural level to choose.  I'm sure a lower number can be shown to work as well.

Comment: Or, take a statement like:  There is no Fibonacci number $F_n$ such that $F_n\equiv 7 \pmod  {13}$  (many variants possible).    That one needs $30$ cases (I think) before you can use induction.

Answer (score 2):

One type of proof is, prove any (optionally positive) integer can be written as $5k + 7j$ for integers $k$, $j$.  You first prove that it is possible to make $1, 2, 3, 4, 5$.  Then by induction any number follows by adding $5$ to a previous case.  And any coprime pair of integers works, doesn't have to be $5$, $7$.

Comment: Right, this one is fine. But easier is to note that 5+5+5 = 7+7 + 1, so you can do induction with only one base case, just subtract two 7s, and add three 5s, and you have a representation for n+1 from n.

Answer (score 1):

The question is

> Examples of natural proofs by induction exercises which needs 3 or more base cases?

I think an elementary natural proof of the parity of the Somos-4
sequence is a nice exercise. Given the Somos-4 sequence of positive integers that satisfies
$$ s_n s_{n-4} = s_{n-1}s_{n-3}+s_{n_2}^2,\quad
   s_n s_{n-5} = -s_{n-1}s_{n-4} +5s_{n-2}s_{n-3} $$
for all integer $n$, with initial terms
$ s_1=s_2=s_3=s_4=1, $
then any five consecutive terms of the sequence has  exactly one even
term and the rest are odd. More precisely, $s_n$ is even iff $n$ is a
multiple of $5$. The proof has two cases depending on $n$ being a
multiple of $5$. The five base cases are for $n=1$ to $n=5$.

Comment: Cool! You are the inventor of these sequences!